# If the window gets closed, open a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to open a function when a browsertab gets closed(also alt + f4). Is there some kind of javascript functionality for that?

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, you can only display a standard confirmation dialog using [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

You can't execute an arbitrary javascript function (for obvious security reasons).

The exception is when this tab was opened from another tab still open and on the same domain : in this case you can check from the opener if the child is still open (but you can't execute the code before it is closed).

You may test it like this :

```
var tab = window.open("index2.html");
setInterval(function(){console.log(tab.window)}, 2000); // shows that tab.window is null as soon as you close the child tab
```

**EDIT :** you may, in fact, do a few things using the onbeforeunload callback but it's not reliable, doesn't work on all browsers, doesn't allow alerts or blocking the closing of the window.

Comment: You can run code in the tab that is being closed. There is however no way to stop it from closing the tab. e.g. `window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  console.log('closing');
  return true;
}` shows `closing` in the console.

Comment: Thanks! How could I check if the child is still open because the window is indeed opened from another window.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery unload function

```
       <script type="text/javascript"> 
       $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).unload(function(){
        alert("Close this window to show Me Unload Event occur..!");
         });
         });
    </script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/unload/

try this

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
       <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
         <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).unload(function(){
        alert("Goodbye!");
         });
        });
       </script>
      </head>
     <body>
     <p>When you click <a href="http://www.google.com">this link</a>, or close the window, an alert box will be triggered.</p>
      </body>
     </html>
```

It is working in my firefox

Comment: In firefox it works but not in chrome or IE or Opera or in Safari